# Is there a way to get Site.com custom property in Lightning code?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, customsetting, community, site.com

Is there a way to get Site.com custom property in Lightning code? Right now I am using custom property for every community (that reflects one site) but wondered if these could be moved to Site.com custom properties? I need to use the properties in components and their helpers.

I've tried `$A.get("{!$Site.c.property_name}")` and `$A.get("{!$Site.property_name}")` but none of those work. I've tried this for standard variables like `$Site.BaseCusomUrl` which according to [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_site.htm) should work for Force.com sites, but even that does not work.

Comment: I think visualforce global variables might not work in lightning component, try creating a property in apex class and pass the value to component.

Comment: That would mean traffic between lightning component and database which I want to avoid. Custom Settings can be used in this manner, but I am slightly against it. Instead of this I created Lightning component 'Global Settings' which has the properties accessible through `design` in the community builder and I put it into Header of the Site and I load the properties from this component.